# TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have an array of for each row in a csv file as followed:

```
[['thxx'], ['too', 'late', 'now', 'dumbass'], ['you', '‘', 're', 'so', 'dumb', '?', '?'], ['thxxx'], ['i', '‘', 'd', 'be', 'fucked']]
```

When I try to pass this on to the lemmatizer like this:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatized_words = [WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in tokened_text]
print(lemmatized_words)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
```

Why is that?

As a side question: Do I need to do this before passing this for Vectorization? I am building an machine learning model and saw the function CountVectorizer in sci kit learn but could not find any information that it does lemmatization and so on beforehand as well.

Comment: each `word` in `tokened_text` seems to be a list of words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some things wrong in your code:

- `WordNetLemmatizer` is a class, you need to instanciate it first
- `tokened_text` is a nested list, hence you need a nested list-comprehension to preserve the structure. Also `lemmatize` is expecting a string.

Here's how you could do this:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

lemmatized_words = [[wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in l] for l in tokened_text]
```

Comment: You can also do ``[nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word) for for word in tokened_text]``

Answer (score 3):

The reason of getting the error is you are missing () after the function name while assigning it to variable

```
xyz = WordNetLemmatizer() --> this bracket is missing leading to the error
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tarun/PycharmProjects/Yumnam_jr_ChatBot/training.py", line 31, in <module>
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letter]
  File "C:/Users/tarun/PycharmProjects/Yumnam_jr_ChatBot/training.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letter]
TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
```

[image]

The error is "Parameter 'self' unfilled". So, what you need to do is install the "package 'self' Version 2020.12.3" and write like the following:-

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(self, word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letter]
words = sorted(set(words))
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write this to make your code work

```
your_variable_here = WordNetLemmatizer()
```

In your code, you haven't added the parentheses `()` after the  `WordNetLemmatizer`.
Add that and you are good to go.